# Карты, закрытие дорог, построение маршрута

Tags: c#, wpf, карты, openstreetmap, картография

Прошу подсказать как реализовать задачу. Необходимо к ПО(WPF) прикрутить карты, на которой будут визуализироваться построенные маршруты, но маршруты должны строится с учетом закрытых дорог, по которым компания не отправляет транспорт по своим субъективным соображениям. Например, пользователь принял решение что по одному из мостов в каком то городе ездить не желательно, он на карте нанес некую метку на этот мост и перекрыл его и как я себе представляю записали это в БД. Теперь все маршруты, которые ложились через этот мост ранее, будут обходить его ближайшем коротким путем. По хорошему, нужна карта, на которой можно наносить ограничения(закрывать дороги), потом через api, в эту карту отправлять координаты точек следования и в ответ получать расстояние с учетом закрытых дорог.
Я никогда не работал с картами, даже не представляю как там все происходит, прошу подтолкнуть в правильном направлении.

Answer (score 0):

Я работал в BingMaps, они имеют широкий функционал, хорошо работают с C#, имеют нормальную документацию.
Вот справка от MS:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877180.aspx
Конечно нужно будет зарегистрироваться и получить ключ, который в бесплатной версии имеет ограничения по количеству запросов в зависимости от того, какой API вы используете. 
После изучения этих материалов задавайте более конкретные вопросы.